# Recursive compare directories by Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to compare directories. I use follow code (sample):

```
def dir_comp(dir1, dir2):
    filecmp.clear_cache()
    DirComp = filecmp.dircmp(dir1, dir2)
    if len(DirComp.left_only) > 0:
        for item in DirComp.left_only:
            print('File/folder', os.path.join(dir1, item), 'exist only in', dir1)
    if len(DirComp.right_only) > 0:
        for item in DirComp.right_only:
            print('File/folder', os.path.join(dir2, item), 'exist only in', dir2)
    for CommonDirs in DirComp.common_dirs:
        new_dir1 = os.path.join(dir1, CommonDirs)
        new_dir2 = os.path.join(dir2, CommonDirs)
        dir_comp(new_dir1, new_dir2)
```

But code show different files only for root directory: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUf2i.png. See screenshot with real different between directories:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpQTe.png.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def print_diff_files(dirs):
    for name in dirs.diff_files:
        diff_files.append(os.path.join(dirs.left, name))
        diff_files.append(os.path.join(dirs.right, name))
    for file_left in dirs.left_only:
        only_left.append(os.path.join(dirs.left, file_left))
    for file_right in dirs.right_only:
        only_right.append(os.path.join(dirs.right, file_right))
    for same_files in dirs.same_files:
        same_files_list.append(os.path.join(dirs.left, same_files))
        same_files_list.append(os.path.join(dirs.right, same_files))
    for sub_dirs in dirs.subdirs.values():
        print_diff_files(sub_dirs)

DirCompare = filecmp.dircmp('old', 'new')
print_diff_files(DirCompare)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the subdirectories `n5/N51` and `n51/N5` are only present in one place (there is no `n5/N5` directory nor a `n51/N51`). The comparison by `dircmp` doesn't recurse into those directories, since it knows ahead of time that every file will be unmatched.

If this isn't what you want, you should probably treat unmatched directories differently from unmatched regular files, using `os.walk` to inspect their contents. Try something like this:

```
def dir_comp(dir1, dir2):
    filecmp.clear_cache()
    DirComp = filecmp.dircmp(dir1, dir2)
    for item in DirComp.left_only:
        path = os.path.join(dir1, item)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            for base, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
                print("Folder", base, "exists only in", dir1)
                for file in files:
                    print("File", os.path.join(base, file), "exists only in", dir1)
        else:
            print('File', path, 'exist only in', dir1)

    for item in DirComp.right_only:
        path = os.path.join(dir2, item)
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            for base, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
                print("Folder", base, "exists only in", dir2)
                for file in files:
                    print("File", os.path.join(base, file), "exists only in", dir2)
        else:
            print('File', os.path.join(path), 'exist only in', dir2)

    for CommonDirs in DirComp.common_dirs:
        new_dir1 = os.path.join(dir1, CommonDirs)
        new_dir2 = os.path.join(dir2, CommonDirs)
        dir_comp(new_dir1, new_dir2)
```

This should print all files that exist in only one folder (even if they're within a directory that only exists in that one). Note that the `DirComp` object you're getting already has the information you need for your recursion on the `CommonDirs`. Check out its [`subdirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html#filecmp.dircmp.subdirs) attribute. You could refactor your code so that you only call `filecmp.dircmp` once, and then pass the results into a recursive function to print them out.